# Dexterity content type unavailable for editing with activated diazo theme?

Tags: plone, dexterity, diazo, plone-4.x

I am creating a new Plone 4.3 site with a Diazo theme, and my users will need to be able to choose between multiple page configurations (layouts). To make those available I have used Dexterity Content Types and set the class to "Item". With the theme deactivated the content shows on the necessary pages and can be edited with the visual editor, but with the Diazo theme active neither the content nor the visual editor appear in the content section when edit is clicked.

Is this not the intended use for what I am trying to achieve? Am I missing follow-up steps after I create the Dexterity Content Type?

I have already rerun buildout and restarted Zope. The secondary page option needs to be something the contributor can select as this is a large organization and individually controlling theme templates with diazo rules.xml would not be efficient.

Comment: Is this happening only with your particular new content type? With all Dexterity types? Or with all content -- Dexterity or not?

Comment: This is happening only with the particular new content type. It is the only Dexterity type which I have introduced.

Comment: I figured it out, it was user error. I had a "class" identified as an "id" in my rules.xml thanks @SteveM for your response.

Answer (score 0):

In my usecases it also usually was some error in the rules file(s). I usually find it helpfull to look at the differences between the diazo styled site and the original (use ?diazo.off=1 after your url to see the unstyled version of your site).
Use the Firepath tab in your Firebug in Firefox to see of your CSS3 or XPath selectors actually select what you mean to select for use in your theme.
Then adjust your rules file(s) accordingly.